# How to differentiate between a circle and square with skimage python?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to detect circles within some surface and then get the centroid and area. 
I do that by checking the eccentricity of the region and the area range I want and it works fine. like the following photo.
the small circle is detected.
[image]

But sometimes structures that are similar to squares gets detected as well because of their eccentricity. 
for example this picture:
[image]

The blue region is detected. 
So my question is how to differentiate between them?
I don't want to detect the square.
Here is the code:

```
    myimage = np.loadtxt("file_113.dat")
    #detecting edges
    edges = feature.canny(myimage, sigma=3, low_threshold=-0.2,high_threshold=0.2)
    labeled_image = label(edges)

    #Locating center of each region
    regions = regionprops(labeled_image)

       for region in regions:
           if  region.area < 100 and region.eccentricity <= 0.4:
               # eccentricity = 0 is a perfect circle
               y0, x0 = region.centroid
               print  ("region " +  str(counter)  + " center at (y,x): " + str(y0) + "," + str(x0))
               print "    region area = " + str(region.area)
               print "    region ecc  = " + str(region.eccentricity)
```

Comment: Please provide code that runs + data.